# Programmatically invoke editorActionListener

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` widget that I'm testing and want to programmatically invoke the registered `editorActionListener` set using `textView.setOnEditorActionListener(...)`. What's the right way to fire this event?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 TextView textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.searchText);//searchText is the id in XML layout
 textview.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);// here it using for search operation..it depends upon your process
 textview.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH)
              {
          //peform operation..  if search key is pressed in keypad, it comes inside the condition..
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```